# Codeigniter - removing index.php

Tags: codeigniter

I downloaded MyClientBase application which is based on code igniter. After the installation, I looked at the MyClientBase's website but the index.php is still there by default.
I tried to remove the index.php using the tips in codeigniter's user guide but it doesn't work.
Is there any solution out there for this issue? Thank you

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaking, but index.php is a CI's bootstrap file, so you have to keep it. All you can do is to remove index.php **from URLs** with mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following .htaccess file to remove index.php. I'm not sure which one the user guide specifies, but I found this to be working perfectly:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Also remove 'index.php' from your config.php file. Good luck!

Comment: Hmmm... You say that without Mod_rewrite you will set the ErrorDoc to index.php yer there you are setting it to 404.php. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Thank for you reply, I tried it and all other solutions I could find and it doesn't work. Just FYI, the application I want to install is MyClientBase http://www.myclientbase.com/ which is based on Code Igniter but somehow instruction from codeigniter on how to remove index.php doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to ask on their support forums because this seems quite application-specific? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it will help but, i use this to remove my index.php from codeigniter url, create a file named `.htaccess` and put it to your codeigniter folder.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```